# Delete Query Syntax

Tags: 8

I am trying to write queries in drupal 8 , I know that I must use the delete() function , however just for testing on my draft I tried the following query and it worked :

```
$connection = \Drupal::database();
$sql = "DELETE FROM role_expire WHERE uid = :uid AND rid = :rid ";
$query_ = $connection->query($sql, array(":uid" => $drupal_user_id ,":rid" => $role_id));
```

My question is should I ADD a execute() at the end like then following example that I found while searching and if yes, then how did my query manage to work without it ? :

```
 $database = \Drupal::database();
 $query = $database->query("DELETE FROM table WHERE name='jane' AND nickmane='" . $nickname . "'");
 $query->execute();
```

same question for the INSERT query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need $query->execute.

Drupal gives this [example](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/database-api/static-queries#Complex%20DELETE%20queries). As you have already mentioned there is recommendation to not use query for simple INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE queries.

And you can see in [Connection::query](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Database!Connection.php/function/Connection%3A%3Aquery/8.9.x) that the query is executed.

Comment: Thank you so much